# Regex searching using list elements to find matches in large document

Tags: python, regex, list

This is my first script, and I am trying to compare two genome files, one of which has more data points than the other.

The content of the files looks like this:

```
rs3094315       1       742429  AA
rs12562034      1       758311  GG
rs3934834       1       995669  CC
```

There are tabs between each field. There's about 500,000 lines in each file.

In order to compare them easily, I wanted to keep only the data points that both the files contained, and discard any data points unique to either of them. To do this, I have created a list of all the DNA positions that are unique and now I am trying to search through each line of the original datafile and print all lines NOT containing these unique DNA positions to a new file.

Everything in my code has worked up until I try to search through the genome file using regex to print all non-unique DNA positions. I can get the script to print all items in the `LaurelSNP_left` list inside the `for` loop, but when I try to use `re.match` for each item, I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/laurelhochstetler/scripts/identify_SNPs.py", line 57, in <module>
    if re.match(item,"(.*)", Line):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 137, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 242, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py", line 500, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.py", line 673, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, 0)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.py", line 308, in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.py", line 401, in _parse
    if state.flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'
```

My question is two-fold:

1. How can I use my list in an regex expression?
2. Is there a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do here?

Here's my code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re #this imports regular expression module
import collections

MomGenome=open('/Users/laurelhochstetler/Documents/genetics fun/genome_Mary_Maloney_Full_20110514145353.txt', 'r')
LaurelGenome=open('/Users/laurelhochstetler/Documents/genetics fun/genome_Laurel_Hochstetler_Full_20100411230740.txt', 'r')
LineNumber = 0 
momSNP = []
LaurelSNP = []
f = open("mom_edit.txt","w")
for Line in MomGenome:
    if LineNumber > 0:
        Line=Line.strip('\n')
        ElementList=Line.split('\t')

        momSNP.append(ElementList[0])

        LineNumber = LineNumber + 1
MomGenome.close()
for Line in LaurelGenome:
    if LineNumber > 0:
        Line=Line.strip('\n')
        ElementList=Line.split('\t')

        LaurelSNP.append(ElementList[0])

        LineNumber = LineNumber + 1
momSNP_multiset = collections.Counter(momSNP)            
LaurelSNP_multiset = collections.Counter(LaurelSNP)
overlap = list((momSNP_multiset and LaurelSNP_multiset).elements())
momSNP_left = list((momSNP_multiset - LaurelSNP_multiset).elements())
LaurelSNP_left = list((LaurelSNP_multiset - momSNP_multiset).elements())
LaurelGenome=open('/Users/laurelhochstetler/Documents/genetics fun/genome_Laurel_Hochstetler_Full_20100411230740.txt', 'r')
i = 0
for Line in LaurelGenome:
    for item in LaurelSNP_left:
            if i < 1961:
                if re.match(item, Line):
                    pass

                else:
                    print Line

            i = i + 1
    LineNumber = LineNumber + 1
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of what the input files look like?

Comment: Cool to see people using their raw data from 23 & me!

Comment: Okay, added some examples of the lines in the files! And yes Stedy, I'm going crazy with the allele data for genealogy purposes!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by a "position"? What makes it unique or non-unique? It's still not clear what you're trying to do, and hence what algorithm might make sense. (@Stedy , if you know, please clarify)

Comment: So, in my data file, each row begins with a unique name which is the name for that specific base pair in the entire genome (called a SNP), for example "rs3094315". There is no rhyme or reason to how these are numbered, so they should be treated as arbitrary names. My mom's genome contains almost all the same SNPs as mine, but mine has about 2,000 extra. I want to reprint my genome without the rows containing those 2,000 extra names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to print every line from file 2 whose ID does not occur in file 1. Make a set of the IDs in file 1, and use them as you loop through file 2:

```
momSNP = set()
for line in MomGenome:
    snp, rest = line.split(None, 1) # Split into two pieces only
    momSNP.add(snp)

for line in MyGenome:
    snp, rest = line.split(None, 1)
    if snp in momSNP:
        print line
```

This only needs to store the 500k SNPs, so it shouldn't be too much of a problem memory-wise.

Comment: This was the best. I didn't realize how inefficient my code was, but it was taking forever to iterate through. This did exactly what I wanted it do in a very small amount of time, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: **I don't think you need regexp for what you're trying to do.**

Long answer: Let's analyse your code.

At the beginning there's:

```
LineNumber = 0 
MomGenome = open('20110514145353.txt', 'r')
for Line in MomGenome:
    if LineNumber > 0:
        Line = Line.strip('\n')
        ElementList = Line.split('\t')

        momSNP.append(ElementList[0])

        LineNumber = LineNumber + 1

MomGenome.close()
```

That it could be improved with the [`with`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) statement, and I guess your line counting is only there to skip some kind of header, I'll use [`next()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#next) for that:

```
with open('20110514145353.txt') as mom_genome:
    next(mom_genome)    # skipping the first line
    for line in mom_genome:
        elements = line.strip().split('\t')
        mom_SNP.append(elements[0])
```

If you noticed I also tried to avoid using `CamelCase` names for variables, this way you'll be following some style guides. I also changed `.strip('\n')` to `.strip()` check the official [`str.strip()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) to see if that still does what you want.
The above can be done on your other file too.

After you read the files there's this line:

```
overlap = list((momSNP_multiset and LaurelSNP_multiset).elements())
```

Are you sure this does what you want?
Shouldn't that `and` be an [`&`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), like:

```
overlap = list((momSNP_multiset & LaurelSNP_multiset).elements())
```

Let's look at this example:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> a = Counter(a=4, b=2, c=0, d=-2)
>>> b = Counter(a=2, b=0, c=0)
>>> a
Counter({'a': 4, 'b': 2, 'c': 0, 'd': -2})
>>> b
Counter({'a': 2, 'c': 0, 'b': 0})
>>> a and b    # This will return b
Counter({'a': 2, 'c': 0, 'b': 0})
>>> c & d    # this will return the common elements
Counter({'a': 2})
```

`a and b` it will return `b` since `bool(a)` is evaulated to `True`, take a look at the [official doc](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not).

After that it comes the match, this is really not clear. You do:

```
LaurelGenome = open('20100411230740.txt', 'r')
i = 0
for Line in LaurelGenome:
    for item in LaurelSNP_left:
        if i < 1961:
            if re.match(item, Line):
                pass
            else:
               print Line

        i = i + 1
    LineNumber = LineNumber + 1
```

So as I was saying at the beginning I think you don't need regexp at all.
**And I think you're trying to do something like:**

```
with open('20100411230740.txt') as laural_genome:
    for line in laureal_genome:
        i = 0
        for item in laurelSNP_left:
            if i > 1960:
                break

            if line.strip().split('\t')[0] == item:
                print line

            i += 1
```

I've guessed a lot during this answer, so feel free to give more information and tell me where I guessed wrong :)

Comment: This was beautiful. I have yet to try the other suggestions people posted, but this worked like a charm. I really appreciate you spelling things out simply for me, as a beginner it's a real help. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The third argument of re.match is for options (see the manual). You're calling it with something bogus (the line number)

Comment: Okay, I actually entered that wrong, I've corrected it to what I originally had: if re.match(item, Line):

Comment: Then you can't still be getting the error message. Did that fix your problem?

Comment: You're right, it no longer is giving me that error anymore! However, I believe there's something amiss with my nested loop, because as soon as it begins running, it prints the same line over and over and over.

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something critical about the problem? I feel this solution is alarmingly less involving than the existing ones. For two different genome files, I have:

```
with file('zzz.txt') as f1:
    first = frozenset([i.strip() for i in f1 if i.strip()])

with file('yyy.txt') as f2:
    common = [i.strip().split('\t') for i in f2 if i.strip() in first]

genomes = {}
for i in common:
    genomes[i[0]] = i[1:]
```

This should print out all duplicates (entries that are common to both files) while requiring no more space than the size of the first read file. Thus, you can speed it up by checking which is a smaller file (perhaps by filesize) beforehand to minimize the memory impact.

Regex does not seem to be necessary here--and if not this solution, frozensets have intersection as well, if you prefer not using list comprehensions.

**EDIT**: Updated to have each iteration in a Python dict.

Comment: As a sidenote, the four .strip() calls are only there because the example content seemed to include blank lines, but each of these processes can be removed if those newlines are copy/paste artifacts.

Comment: You'll need to split on tabs and index by the first field only, see his comment about SNPs.